# iOS: Sprite kit what is the best practice for setting proper size for different iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, resize, sprite-kit

I use sprite kit to make universal game.
I want to scale original sprites to use it on other devices. My game have pixel graphics so scaling is okay for me.

I'm thinking for best approach when creating sprite and it's size:

```
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "myTexture")
texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture, size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
```

I see two ways to do that.
**1. Calculate the device ratio.**

```
let deviceScreenRatio = 300.0 / 620.0
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
```

Set up the sprite and then recount, resize it's size:

```
sprite.size = CGSize(width: Double(sprite.size.width) * deviceScreenRatio, height: Double(sprite.size.height) * deviceScreenRatio)
```

**2. Another way. Count different sizes, store it into the .plist and then use it:**

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture, size: CGSize(width: widthFromPlist, height: heightFromPlist))
```

What is the best way or you know alternative solution?

Comment: It really depends on the app and how you want to treat the different devices. Scale up, or just regard them as larger screens.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D yes, I understand this, but what is more resource efficient way, create sprite then resize it or init sprite already with sprite or this doesn't matter?

Comment: not sure what you mean but you end up having a sprite either way, what matters is the size of the texture

Comment: I think the best solution is make all your image for iPad then scale down with the first option. Do not forget atlas:)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I mean that in the first way I create sprite node with texture and it's already will have a some size, right?  And after this I resize it by setting it's size to another one that I need. Is this more resource-consuming action than creating sprite node already with size?

Comment: @Totka thanks for advices and I doing so, except this question, I add some explanation in response to LearnCocos2D.

Comment: whether you change size instantly or later doesn't matter

Comment: @LearnCocos2D oh, I thought it is:/ So, my question is doesn't make sense